# Understanding this recursion function

Tags: java, loops, recursion, tail-recursion

I am altering/improving this recursive function. My intention is to add a global class variable nrOfFails to store all the iterations where the search was unsuccessful.

I call the function as follows:

```
{
    ArrayList<Integer> solutions = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] money1= {2,2,2,5,10,10,20}
    int targe1 = 24
    System.out.print(solutions(money1,target1,solutions))
}

 /**
   * Returns the number of ways of creating specified target value as a sum of money starting with c
   * @param money the set of coins
   * @param c Index of the array
   * @param target the amount to give back
   * @return number of ways
   */
  private static int solutions(int[] money, int c, int target, ArrayList<Integer> s)
  {
    assert money!=null : "array should be initialized";
    assert c>=0&&c<=money.length;
    nrOfFails = 0;

    if(target==0)
    {
      showSolution(s);
      return 1;
    }
    if(target<0)
      return 0;
    if(c>=money.length)
      return 0;
    else
    {
      s.add(money[c]);
      int with = solutions(money, c + 1, target - money[c], s);
      s.remove(s.size()-1);
      int without = solutions(money, c + 1, target,s);
      return with + without;
    }
  }

  private static void showSolution(ArrayList<Integer> s)
  {
    System.out.print(s);
  }
```

I came up with a primitive way of 'counting' the unsuccessful iterations, but I would like to use recursion to solve this problem.

As for the primitive solution. I tried to check if at any iteration the content of money[] there was a value that didn't contain a multiple of the target quantity, then we searched in vain. Using a for, and a counter to check if there was or not a common multiple, if there wasn't any then we searched in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the "iterations where the search was unsuccessful" which you wish to count.

One such case is when you pass a negative `target` to the recursive call (which means `target - money[c] < 0` in the `solutions(money, c + 1, target - money[c], s)` recursive call).

Another such case is when you run out of array elements before reaching the target sum (i.e. when `c >= money.length`).

Therefore you should increment your `nrOfFails` counter in these two cases. I unified them into a single condition, to make the code shorter:

```
static int nrOfFails = 0;
private static int solutions(int[] money, int c, int target, ArrayList<Integer> s)
{
    assert money != null : "array should be initialized";
    assert c >= 0 && c <= money.length;

    if (target == 0) {
        showSolution(s);
        return 1;
    } else if (target < 0 || c >= money.length) {
        nrOfFails++;
        return 0;
    } else {
        s.add(money[c]);
        int with = solutions(money, c + 1, target - money[c], s);
        s.remove(s.size() - 1);
        int without = solutions(money, c + 1, target, s);
        return with + without;
    }
}
```

You have to reset the static variable to `0` prior to the first call to `solutions`.

Note that you forgot the `c` argument in your initial call to the recursive method. I added it here. I also added resetting and printing of `nrOfFails`:

```
nrOfFails = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> solutions = new ArrayList<>();
int[] money1= {2,2,2,5,10,10,20};
int target = 24;
System.out.println(solutions(money1,0,target,solutions));
System.out.println ("number of fails = " + nrOfFails);
```

This produces the following output:

```
[2, 2, 10, 10]
[2, 2, 20]
[2, 2, 10, 10]
[2, 2, 20]
[2, 2, 10, 10]
[2, 2, 20]
6
number of fails = 110
```